# php - using a variable as formula

Tags: php

According to user input I perform a query and then some math on the results. My problem is that I'm storing the math in a variable, and can't get it read as math. For example:

```
$Math=($ArryDBs[$i]['GSE45728_01']+$ArryDBs[$i]['GSE45728_02'])//this is constructed upon user input

echo "<table>";//this is coded after Select, where $ArryDBs is generated
  for ($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td> 1) From Math: ".$Math."</td>";
      echo "<td> 2) Direct: ".($ArryDBs[$i]['GSE45728_01']+$ArryDBs[$i]['GSE45728_02'])."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

The output is as follows (note that expressions for 1) and 2) are the same):

```
1) From Math: ($ArryDBs[$i]['GSE45728_01']+$ArryDBs[$i]['GSE45728_02']) 2) Direct: 8.23018
1) From Math: ($ArryDBs[$i]['GSE45728_01']+$ArryDBs[$i]['GSE45728_02']) 2) Direct: 12.46399
1) From Math: ($ArryDBs[$i]['GSE45728_01']+$ArryDBs[$i]['GSE45728_02']) 2) Direct: 15.08906
```

Values in 2) Direct is what I want. But it change according to Users input. Thats why I'm storing the expression in a variable. Its reading the variable literally as a string. All related questions suggest using eval(), although always people (and the manual itself) discourages its use.

My question: how can I get $Math read as an operation to perform?

Comment: If I substitute the variables above with floats I get the expected output: `1) From Math: 67 2) Direct: 67`.  Have you tried casting your variables to the proper numerical values?

Comment: @Crackertastic: I'm not sure really if are proper numerical values, and will review my code. For simplicity I wrote $Math directly, but it is actually constructed with things like `$ForMath[$key].="\$ArrayDBs[\$i]['".$key."_".$matches[1][$n]."']";$Math=array_values($ForMath);` and in the code of my question is called as $Math[0] or similar. Anyway, when echoing the "reading" is the same as the expression I want to evaluate. I will review carefully my code (I'm by no means an expert...). Thank you.

Comment: Usually PHP is good about taking strings that it _"thinks"_ are numbers and doing the casting for you before arithmetic, but PHP is by no means perfect.  You can always try putting things like `(float)` or `(int)` in front of variables to tell PHP to cast a variable.  PHP's [settype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) function is also helpful since it will return a boolean letting you know if the cast was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is not recursively executable. You cannot embed PHP code inside a string and expect PHP to also execute it.

e.g.

```
<?php

echo "Hello <?php echo 'world' ?>";

?>
```

is going to print out, literally:

```
Hello <?php echo 'world' ?>
```

If you want the contents of a variable to be treated as "math" (e.g. php code), then you'd have to execute those contents, e.g.

```
php > $foo = "echo 1+1;";
php > eval($foo);
2
```

and note that the variable's contents have to be VALID php code. `eval('1+1')` will calculate `2`, but since that value isn't assigned anywhere or returned to anything, it'll simply be thrown away.

---

comment followup:

```
php > $a = 1;
php > $b = 2;
php > $c = 3;
php > $d = 4;
php > $foo = '$bar = ($a + $b) * ($c + $d);';
php > eval($foo);
php > echo $bar;
21
```

works out as expected.

Comment: You're right. Thats the problem. But I still can't "fully" evaluate $Math[0], that reads: ($ArrayDBs[$i]['GSE45728_01']+$ArrayDBs[$i]['GSE45728_02']). When I tried with `eval("\$Math2 = \"$Math[0]\";");`, the response is `(Array['GSE45728_01']+Array['GSE45728_02'])` (the code is evaluating `$ArrayDBs[$i]`, but not the second component of the array (´['GSE45728_02']`). Any ideas?

Comment: standard php behavior for multidimensional arrays in double-quoted strings. read up about "Complex (curly) syntax": http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Almost there. I need to study and understand much more, and will try it myself, but if somebody can help me only a bit more I will be grateful. If the variable is defined as `({$ArregloDBs[$i]['GSE45728_01']}+{$ArregloDBs[$i]['GSE45728_02']})/({$ArregloDBs[$i]['GSE45728_03']}+{$ArregloDBs[$i]['GSE45728_04']})`, I obtain `(5.38084+2.84934)/(3.28155+3.96505)`. Id est, it is correctly evaluating the array values, but is not performing the operations between the array values. What else do I need? maybe an eval() of the eval()?

Comment: Got it! I appreciate it a lot really. The difference between quote, double quotes, inverse quotes, jumping quotes, smiling quotes and so on is driving me crazy. Just for completeness, it worked out defining the variable as something like `$Math=($ArrayDBs[$i]['GSE45728_01']+$ArrayDBs[$i]['GSE45728_02'])/($ArrayDBs[$i]['GSE45728_03']+$ArrayDBs[$i]['GSE45728_04'])`, and then `$foo = '$bar = '.$Math.';';eval($foo);echo $bar;`. Thanks again.